# Inner Join returning Column Name

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp

I'm getting a strange error on mysql.

My query is:

```
SELECT 
    'u.id', 
    'u.primeiroNome', 
    'u.ultimoNome', 
    'u.email', 
    'p.cpf' 
FROM user as u 
INNER JOIN pacientes as p ON u.id = p.user_id
```

and here is the return
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSqyp.png

this is running on wamp 2.5 64bits

Comment: Why are you quoting the field name in the select statement?  get rid of the quotes, try again

Comment: I am not a mysql expert...as a matter of fact I have never done a mysql query in my life,but why is the columns it quotes? It will put out x amount of rows with 'u.id', 
    'u.primeiroNome', 
    'u.ultimoNome', 
    'u.email', 
    'p.cpf' as the row values

Comment: Therefore the columns will have "anonymous" names

Comment: The result returned by this query is not at all strange, it's defined behavior. And it's not really a MySQL error at all. It's entirely valid to return a string literal as an expression in a SELECT list. If the intent is not to return literals, remove the single quotes, and MySQL will see those expressions in the SELECT list as identifiers of columns in the referenced tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the simple quotes of your query:

```
SELECT u.id
    ,u.primeiroNome
    ,u.ultimoNome
    ,u.email
    ,p.cpf
FROM `user` as u
INNER JOIN pacientes as p ON p.user_id = u.id
```

Simple quotes are interpreted as string values and that the reason of your "anomaly" or problem.

Here is the same query but with use of backticks:

```
SELECT u.`id`
    ,u.`primeiroNome`
    ,u.`ultimoNome`
    ,u.`email`
    ,p.`cpf`
FROM `user` as u
INNER JOIN pacientes as p ON p.`user_id` = u.`id`
```

It's important to understand the distinction between single quotes and backticks when working with SQL queries.

Here you'll find more information about the use of these characters: [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I think the ' should be ` (backtick) if you must escape a name.